# How to change array elements

Tags: mongodb

How to write correct this part of query:

```
parseFloat(data.versions.0.content.axdducvoxb) ?**
```

I try to change my fields type from string to float. I have a lot of documents with main element and history of same elements:

```
axdducvoxb
versions.0.content.axdducvoxb
versions.1.content.axdducvoxb
versions.2.content.axdducvoxb
.......
```

Code:

```
db.documents.find().forEach(function(data) {     
    db.documents.update({_id:data._id},
                        {$set: {axdducvoxb:parseFloat(data.axdducvoxb)}}); 
})
```

When I use it everything is OK:

```
db.documents.find({"type": "chair"}).forEach(function(data) {   
   db.documents.update({_id:data._id},
                       {$set:{'versions.0.content.axdducvoxb':
                               parseFloat(data.axdducvoxb)}}); 
})
```

When I use it I replace `versions.0.content.axdducvoxb` element to `data.axdducvoxb` element

But when I make correct replace I see the Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Code:

```
db.documents.find({"type": "chair"}).forEach(function(data) {   
    db.documents.update({_id:data._id},
                       {$set:{'versions.0.content.axdducvoxb':
                               parseFloat(data.versions.0.content.axdducvoxb)}}); 
})
```

data.versions[0].content.axdducvoxb does not work too

Comment: When creating a question/answer, it's helpful if you format the code and text using Markdown syntax documented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). It makes it a lot easier for others to help.

Comment: try `data.versions[0].content.axdducvoxb`

Comment: data.versions[0].content.axdducvoxb does not work too                                            TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined