# mongodb php Strings to float values

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I tried make it from mongodb console, but it doesn't work, because I can not work with arrays like afrray[0] afrray[1] afrray[2] etc

[How to change array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765005/how-to-change-array-elements)

Now I try to do it from php, but i see only zeros in base ((((

What do I wrong?

```
$out = $collection->update(
        array("type" => 'chair'), array('$set' => array( 'vmfqvfjptu' => floatval('vmfqvfjptu'), 
        'versions.0.content.vmfqvfjptu'=> floatval('versions.0.content.vmfqvfjptu'),
        'versions.1.content.vmfqvfjptu'=> floatval('versions.1.content.vmfqvfjptu'),
        'versions.2.content.vmfqvfjptu'=> floatval('versions.2.content.vmfqvfjptu'),
        'versions.3.content.vmfqvfjptu'=> floatval('versions.3.content.vmfqvfjptu')
        )),
        array("multiple" => true)   
);
```

**How can I send string from database near floatval('versions.0.content.vmfqvfjptu') ?**

**This script works good from mongo console. There are 4 scripts. Every one takes string from database, convert string to float and save float to database (for each documents in collection).**

```
 db.documents.find({ 'fwtweaeeba' : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { 
    obj.fwtweaeeba = parseFloat( obj.fwtweaeeba ); 
    db.documents.save(obj); } );    

db.documents.find({ 'versions.0.content.fwtweaeeba' : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { 
    obj.versions[0].content.fwtweaeeba = parseFloat( obj.versions[0].content.fwtweaeeba ); 
    db.documents.save(obj); } );

db.documents.find({ 'versions.1.content.fwtweaeeba' : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { 
    obj.versions[1].content.fwtweaeeba = parseFloat( obj.versions[1].content.fwtweaeeba );  
    db.documents.save(obj); } );

db.documents.find({ 'versions.2.content.fwtweaeeba' : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { 
    obj.versions[2].content.fwtweaeeba = parseFloat( obj.versions[2].content.fwtweaeeba );  
    db.documents.save(obj); } );
```

I need make the same with php because I have a lot of fields in every document to convert...

**It works !!!! Thank you, Sammaye !!! You really helped me!!!**

```
foreach($db->documents->find(array("type" => "chair")) as $document){
//  my_dump($document[_id]);
    $db->documents->update(
        array('_id' => $document[_id]),
        array(
            '$set' => array(
                'versions.0.content.axdducvoxb' => (float)$document['versions'][0]['content']['axdducvoxb'],
                'versions.1.content.axdducvoxb' => (float)$document['versions'][1]['content']['axdducvoxb'],
                'versions.2.content.axdducvoxb' => (float)$document['versions'][2]['content']['axdducvoxb'],
                'axdducvoxb' => (float)$document['axdducvoxb']
            )
        ),
        array('$multi' => true)
    );


}
```

Comment: WHat does `floatval('versions.0.content.vmfqvfjptu')` reference? It wouldn't reference anything in JS either (shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from the question you linked:

```
db.documents.find({"type": "chair"}).forEach(function(data) {   
    db.documents.update({_id:data._id},
                       {$set:{'versions.0.content.axdducvoxb':
                               parseFloat(data.versions.0.content.axdducvoxb)}}); 
})
```

Would be:

```
foreach($db->documents->find(array("type" => "chair")) as $document){
    $db->documents->update(
        array('_id' => $document['_id']),
        array(
            '$set' => array(
                'versions.0.content.axdducvoxb' => floatval($document['versions'][0]['content']['axdducvoxb'])
            )
        )
    );
}
```

There done.
good answer

Comment: I see zeros when i use it (((

Comment: @user3469031 what is the structure your trying to send in? Can you show a full example with outputs?

Comment: @user3469031 Ok I see now, I will edit, you can't reflect the document within the single query in MongoDB yet unlike SQL

Comment: @user3469031 OK try something closer to that

Comment: $document['versions'][0]['content']['axdducvoxb'] this string dont send value (((

Comment: @user3469031 can you edit with the structure of your document? That should work now

Comment: @user3469031 I have noticed that `axdducvoxb` is 0

Comment: axdducvoxb is 0 because i did it 0 with mongo console

Comment: numbers are converted to float, but they are not saved to database

Answer (score -1):

For php, this

```
floatval('versions.0.content.vmfqvfjptu')
```

evaluates to false. Because it's not the value of the field from the db's collection

Comment: Can you add what one should do instead?